# No such module Parse using Swift in Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, frameworks

There are several questions addressing this issue already, but all of them (I think) are in reference to earlier versions of Parse using an objective-C bridging header to connect the framework.  I am using the latest version of Parse that has support for Swift directly, which is a different setup process.

I've downloaded and added Parse to Xcode in the `Build Phases` -> `Link Binary With Libraries`. The directions on their website are extremely straightforward...download the SDK, add it to Xcode, import it, and done.

Parse seems to be added properly everywhere it should be:

[image]

[image]

But alas, when I use `import Parse`, I get a `no such module` error.  I've tried adding the framework search path `$(PROJECT_DIR)` under `Build Settings` both recursively and non-recursively, and a few other recommendations from the other questions addressing this issue, but with no luck.

I'm wondering if this could be an issue with Parse or the Xcode beta, since both are extremely new, but I'm assuming the error is on my end, just not exactly sure where to look since the quickstart guide on Parse.com seemed so simple.

Comment: You can easily add [parse](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX) to your project using CocoaPods [here's the link for parse SDK](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX) On parse.com there is quick start projects for working with ios/swift comes with everything you need. [2]: https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/swift

Comment: I've gone through the quickstart on parse.com several times, and it still gives me an error, which is the issue.

Comment: try this step by step, works for me:
http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/connect-your-swift-application-to-parse-com/

Comment: I've tried doing it with the bridging header, but the latest version of Parse has support for Swift which doesn't require the bridging header.

Comment: Is your platform set to IOS 9 in your podfile(platform :ios, '9.0')? I ran into similar problems from omitting it a while ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently if you drag the Parse library to the 'Link with Binary Libraries' section, you will continue to get this error.

**You have to drag Parse to the project navigator for it to properly import.**

Since it should work regardless of where you drag it into Xcode, it is possible this could be a problem with the Xcode 7.1 beta or the updated Parse API for Swift support.  I'm not entirely sure, but either way, it's a really simple fix, so not a big deal.

Comment: Omg thank you. Couldn't figure this out for an hour.