# I keep getting No such module 'Parse' error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I think you may know what I error I am talking about as it has been discussed in previous stack forms. I have read all of these and tried everything but this still isn't working for me.

[No such module Parse using Swift in Xcode 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154405/no-such-module-parse-using-swift-in-xcode-7-1)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621187/no-such-module-parse-xcode-7-1-ios-9-1

[No Such Module 'Parse'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663180/no-such-module-parse)

I have followed tutorials on Cocoa Pods and I even tried using older version of parse dependencies

http://www.webdevils.com/parse-swift-with-cocoapods/

https://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/10/12/how-to-use-the-parse-sdk-with-xcode-7-and-ios-9

I have spent way too long trying to figure this out. Is it even my fault or is it Parse's fault. Their newest SDK was released 12/12 which is very recent so it is tough to believe it wouldn't work.

```
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!
target 'What\'s Up' do
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseUI'
end

target 'What\'s UpTests' do
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseUI'
end

target 'What\'s UpUITests' do
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseUI'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

This has worked for me in the past:

1. Click your root project
2. Select your target application
3. Select build phases
4. open Link Binary With library
5. add your dependency
6. rebuild

[image]

Comment: I owe you my life :) I spent 3 hours trying every possible thing I could and I did this at least 10 times...now it works. I just tested this out and it seems to be true, but you before you can add the import statements and try to build the app you have to build the app with the frameworks added and no import statements. I am new to this so I am not sure if that is common knowledge or some weird bug but it works now so thank you.